# How to configure maximum internet speed?

Tags: data-connection, mobile-data, data-monitoring, data-transfer

I would like to set a maximum value for upload and download speeds. I want to do this so that the monthly consumption of bandwidth per month would be reduced. This would help reduce the costs associated with internet usage. Is it possible to configure these parameters on Android devices?